# Optimizing Matrix multiplication using Go routines without inbuilt functions

Tags: go, concurrency, matrix-multiplication, goroutine

I have the below code for matrix multiplication using Go Routines

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var col = 100
    var row = 150
    var randMatrixA [][]int
    var randMatrixB [][]int
    chA := make(chan [][]int)
    chB := make(chan [][]int)

    wg.Add(1)
    go genMat(row, col, chA, &wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go genMat(col, row, chB, &wg)

    wg.Wait()

    randMatrixA = <-chA
    randMatrixB = <-chB
    fmt.Println(randMatrixA)

    fmt.Println(randMatrixB)

    fmt.Println("The Go Result of Matrix Multiplication = ")
    start := time.Now()
    c := doCalc(randMatrixA, randMatrixB)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)

    fmt.Println(c)

    fmt.Printf("Time taken to calculate %s \n", elapsed)
}
func genMat(row int, col int, ch chan<- [][]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    nM := make([][]int, col)
    for i := 0; i < col; i++ {
        nM[i] = make([]int, row)
    }
    generateNums(nM)
    wg.Done()
    ch <- nM
}
func generateNums(randMatrix [][]int) {
    for i, innerArray := range randMatrix {
        for j := range innerArray {
            randMatrix[i][j] = rand.Intn(100)
        }
    }
}
func rowCount(inM [][]int) int {
    return (len(inM))
}
func colCount(inM [][]int) int {
    return (len(inM[0]))
}
func doCalc(inA [][]int, inB [][]int) [][]int {
    var i, j int
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    chC := make(chan [][]int)
    m := rowCount(inA) // number of rows the first matrix
    p := rowCount(inB) // number of rows the second matrix
    q := colCount(inB) // number of columns the second matrix
    k := 0
    total := 0
    var nM [][]int
    wg.Add(1)
    go genMat(m, q, chC, &wg)
    nM = <-chC
    wg.Wait()
    for i = 0; i < m; i++ {
        for j = 0; j < q; j++ {
            for k = 0; k < p; k++ {
                total = total + inA[i][k]*inB[k][j]
            }
            nM[i][j] = total
            total = 0
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    return nM
}
```

I am using Go Routines to optimize the execution. Two go routines to randomly generate matrixA and MatrixB and another to calculate the result MatrixC

The total execution time is averaging around 2.4 ms. But I want to make it somewhere between 1 to 2 ms or even lesser.

Can any folks out there suggest areas of optimizations in the code by utilizing go routines and without using in-built functions:)

Comment: Use a better algorithm and make sure memory/cache bandwidth sn't the limiting factor.

Comment: Any suggestion on which algorithm to use?

Comment: Googel is strong in answering such question. Note that tiny matrices of 100x150: It makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not using the default library package? `https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat`

I implemented and it is faster than your algorithm (~1.1ms, multiple run results are in below).

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat"
)

func main() {
    const matrixSize = 150
    matrixA := generateRandomMatrix(matrixSize, matrixSize)
    matrixB := generateRandomMatrix(matrixSize, matrixSize)

    A := mat.NewDense(matrixSize, matrixSize, matrixA)
    B := mat.NewDense(matrixSize, matrixSize, matrixB)
    C := mat.NewDense(matrixSize, matrixSize, nil)
    start := time.Now()
    C.Mul(A, B)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Duration %s\n", elapsed)
}

func generateRandomMatrix(rows, cols int) []float64 {
    matrix := make([]float64, rows*cols)
    for i := range matrix {
        matrix[i] = rand.Float64()
    }
    return matrix
}
```

**Elapsed Duration (multiple run):**

```
Duration 1.4275ms
Duration 1.0722ms
Duration 1.3446ms
Duration 1.1604ms
Duration 1.0194ms
Duration 596.3µs
Duration 1.2118ms
Duration 925.2µs
Duration 1.3754ms
```

Comment: liked ur approach .... but the challenge here is to leverage concurrency through go routines without using in-built functions...